# Running continuous PHP applications on free Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

It is possible to run continuous PHP applications on free Heroku?
I run the PHP irc bot via browser by this code:

```
<?php
exec("(cd php-irc;/app/php/bin/php ./bot.php bot.conf &) > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
?>
```

Bot turns off after about an hour :(

Comment: Have you looked at background jobs? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

Comment: It's looks bit complicated and no tutorials for PHP but I'll try it. It is working on free heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested jszobody I use background jobs.
I executed

```
heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext:/app/apache/lib
```

and created Procfile with contents:

```
web: sh boot.sh
worker: cd ~/php-irc/ && php bot.php bot.conf
```

and executed:

```
heroku ps:scale web=0 worker=1
```

Seems it works without problems. Thanks!